# ¿Como debo realizar de manera correcta una función que me retorne los resultados en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

estoy intentando crear una función que me devuelva como resultado los campos que estoy básicamente sumando, pero no puedo generarla de buena manera, siempre me da problemas con el resultado, el error que me devuelve es

> ERROR:  la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado
>   HINT:  Si quiere descartar los resultados de un SELECT, utilice PERFORM.
>   CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL consultarcarga(date,date,integer) en la línea 5 en sentencia SQL
>   SQL state: 42601

El código de la función que intento crear es el siguiente:

Cabe destacar que si ejecuto solo el código sql, este si funciona y si me trae resultados.

```
CREATE FUNCTION consultarCarga(d1 DATE, d2 DATE, i integer) returns varchar language plpgsql as $$
DECLARE
 rec varchar;
BEGIN  
  select carga_termica.fecha, sum(carga_termica.carga_interna) as
carga_interna,
    sum(carga_termica.ganancia_solar) as ganancia_solar,
sum(carga_termica.ground) as ground,
    sum(carga_termica.muros) as muros, sum(carga_termica.particiones)
as particiones, sum(carga_termica.qs) as qs,
    sum(carga_termica.requerimiento_energetico_total) as
requerimiento_energetico_total,
    sum(carga_termica.techos) as techos, sum(carga_termica.ventanas)
as ventanas, sum(carga_termica.ventilacion) as ventilacion
    from carga_termica
    inner join espacios
    on espacios.id=carga_termica.esp_id
    inner join edificios
    on edificios.id=espacios.edif_id
    where calibracion = true
    and edificios.id=i
    and fecha >= d1 and fecha <= d2
    group by fecha
    order by fecha ASC;
    return rec;
end $$;
```

Y la llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT consultarCarga('2018-10-10','2018-10-12',1);
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay algunos conceptos que debes conocer...

- Para retornar algo en una función en postgresql debes asignarle el valor a lo que retornas por ejemplo :

```
rec: = (select...);
return rec;

---o retornar la consulta
return query select...
```

- Otro aspecto es  que lo que retornas dede ser del mismo tipo de dato de la funcion, y al parecer necesitas retornar varias columnas, lo cual se ajustaría a un tipo de dato **record** y no un **varchar** como lo tienes puesto, tal vez definir un tipo de datos que contenga esos atributos de la consulta... asegurate que tu conuslta retorne un solo registro... de lo contrario te lo digo en el siguinte punto

```
CREATE FUNCTION consultarCarga(d1 DATE, d2 DATE, i integer) returns record language plpgsql as $$
DECLARE
 rec record;
BEGIN  
  rec:= (select carga_termica.fecha, sum(carga_termica.carga_interna) as
carga_interna,
    sum(carga_termica.ganancia_solar) as ganancia_solar,
sum(carga_termica.ground) as ground,
    sum(carga_termica.muros) as muros, sum(carga_termica.particiones)
as particiones, sum(carga_termica.qs) as qs,
    sum(carga_termica.requerimiento_energetico_total) as
requerimiento_energetico_total,
    sum(carga_termica.techos) as techos, sum(carga_termica.ventanas)
as ventanas, sum(carga_termica.ventilacion) as ventilacion
    from carga_termica
    inner join espacios
    on espacios.id=carga_termica.esp_id
    inner join edificios
    on edificios.id=espacios.edif_id
    where calibracion = true
    and edificios.id=i
    and fecha >= d1 and fecha <= d2
    group by fecha
    order by fecha ASC);
    return rec;
end $$;

-- si es record debes llamarla de la siguiente manera, con el casteo correspondiente
select * from consultarCarga('2018-10-10','2018-10-12',1) as (fecha date,carga_interna numeric.....)
```

- Otro detalle  es que tu consulta puede retornar varia filas, para eso debes definir la función de tipo **TABLE** o **SETOF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION consultarCarga(d1 DATE, d2 DATE, i integer) returns TABLE(fecha date, carga_interna numeric, ...) language plpgsql as $$
DECLARE
BEGIN  
  return query select carga_termica.fecha, sum(carga_termica.carga_interna) as
carga_interna,
    sum(carga_termica.ganancia_solar) as ganancia_solar,
sum(carga_termica.ground) as ground,
    sum(carga_termica.muros) as muros, sum(carga_termica.particiones)
as particiones, sum(carga_termica.qs) as qs,
    sum(carga_termica.requerimiento_energetico_total) as
requerimiento_energetico_total,
    sum(carga_termica.techos) as techos, sum(carga_termica.ventanas)
as ventanas, sum(carga_termica.ventilacion) as ventilacion
    from carga_termica
    inner join espacios
    on espacios.id=carga_termica.esp_id
    inner join edificios
    on edificios.id=espacios.edif_id
    where calibracion = true
    and edificios.id=i
    and fecha >= d1 and fecha <= d2
    group by fecha
    order by fecha ASC;

end $$;
```

pero si es una simple consulta, te recomiendo que uses funciones en SQL y no en PLPGSQL

saludos